# Is the zero expectation of the residuals in Gauss-Markov theorem really an hypothesis?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, regression, parameter-estimation, least-squares

Wikipedia says

> The Gauss–Markov theorem states that the ordinary least squares (OLS) estimator has the lowest sampling variance within the class of linear unbiased estimators, if the errors in the linear regression model are uncorrelated, have equal variances and expectation value of zero.

Alright. But the fact is that, when I compute the expectation of the residuals taking into account the OLS estimator, I naturally obtain $0$.

So my question is: do we need to *explictly* consider the zero-expectation of the residuals as an hypothesis ? Isn't it already *induced* by the computation of the estimator through OLS ?

Comment: The OLS model is $${\bf Y} = {\bf X}\beta+\epsilon.$$ When the Wikipedia article mentions the errors **in the model**, it is referring to $\epsilon$, not the residuals. The residuals can be thought of as the errors in our estimate, which are distinct from the errors in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You are confusing residuals and errors; they are not the same. The former are the terms $\hat{e}_i = y - X \hat{\beta}$ and, in particular, they are estimated. The errors correspond to the random component in your model to which you have to ascribe some assumptions. Notice that these assumptions do not need to be met by your residuals: for instance, one may assume the errors are independent, but OLS residuals will sum to zero, showing they are not independent.
2. Setting the mean of the errors to zero is done to ensure the model is [identifiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifiability). Notice that if I consider the model $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \epsilon$ with $E(\epsilon) = \mu$, then this model cannot be distinguished from $y = \beta_0^\prime + \beta_1x + \epsilon^\prime$ where $\beta_0^\prime = \beta_0 + \mu$ and $E(\epsilon^\prime) = 0$. Without this, parameter estimation makes little sense (and hence you would have no Gauss-Markov theorem).

Comment: At your point 2, I guess you are talking about the *errors*, not the *residuals*, right ? I think you made a mistake there ? Because you can not set the mean of the residuals, you can just compute it. What you can set is the mean of the errors, right ?

Comment: @MysteryGuy you're correct, I meant the mean of the errors